# How do I exit a serial terminal buffer using keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient

I am using emacs for Windows.

I start a new terminal using serial-term.  Once in that buffer, I cannot open a minibuffer or use meta keys to escape this shell. The only way I can navigate out is using the mouse to click on the buffer I would like to switch to. Is there a keyboard command that can escape from serial mode?

Comment: You should be able to use `C-x` commands by just typing them with `C-c` instead, so `C-x o` becomes `C-c o` in `char-mode` `term`.

Comment: That works for `C-x` commands. Is there a way to run `M-x ` commands without navigating to another buffer?

Comment: Look at `term-line-mode` (`C-c C-j`).  Compare with `term-char-mode` (`C-c C-k`).

Comment: Alternatively, do things like `(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") #'execute-extended-command)`

Comment: Thanks for both those answers. Here is the my fix in my `.emacs`:
`(eval-after-load 'term
  '(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") #'execute-extended-command)
)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the my fix in my `.emacs`:

```
(eval-after-load 'term
  '(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") #'execute-extended-command))
```

This reassigns the meta key after entering terminal mode.